# Vertically center UL and horizontally align LI children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want my `UL` to do the following things:

- I want to have my `UL` vertically centered in `Nav`. I tried using a
  wrapper with `display: table;` but that didn't work.
- I want my `LI`'s to be evenly spread horizontally across the width of
  the `UL`, which I did with `display: flex;` just not perfectly.
- And I need it to be independent from the height because that might change later on.

I have the following code:

```css
nav {
  width: 780px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>sample</li>
    <li>sample</li>
    <li>sample</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lat54o4/1/)

I hope you can help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a bit of tweaking to your flexbox layout:

```css
nav {
  width: 780px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
}

nav ul {
  height: 100%;                     /* take height of nav parent */
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;                  /* remove default UL padding */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;    /* horizontal alignment (applies to child elements) */
  align-items: center;              /* vertical alignment (applied to child elements) */
}

nav ul li {
  /* display: inline-block;         <-- not necessary */
  /* margin: 0 auto;                <-- not necessary */
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>sample</li>
    <li>sample</li>
    <li>sample</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lat54o4/6/)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using display:table & display:table-cell. Please check this updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lat54o4/7/)

```
nav {
    width: 780px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: pink;
    display: table;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    width: 33.33%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
}
```